# How can I make the div match that of the parent

Tags: html, css

I want to make the yellow and pink area (div p2 and p2c1) to match that of their parent, i.e. white.

When I try `height: 100%` it covers the whole screen, not just the parent div.

[Here is a jsbin](http://jsbin.com/jitezupexu/2/edit) of the below:

```css
body {
  background: #EEE;
}
#container {
  display: float;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: white;
}
#p1 {
  display: float;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: blue;
}
#p2 {
  display: float;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: yellow;
}
#c1 {
  display: float;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}
#c2 {
  display: float;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
}
#p2c1 {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="p1">
    <div id="c1">Content here gdfgd gdf</div>
    <div id="c2">aaaaa logkljfd lkfj skfjs] lkdjf lsdkjfsdlkjfsdk ljflkdsjfljsd
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="p2">
    <div id="p2c1">
      blah blah blah
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It would be better to include the html in the question.

Comment: Isn't it just [Position: absolute](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp) you need to be able to do that?

Comment: Thanks misterManSam for editing the question.

Comment: uruloke: hmm... not sure. That's why I am asking...

Answer (score 0):

First, you should set `height` to `container` div. Then you can set children div's height.

[SEE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/zifulegipa/1/)

Updated:
If you don't want fix to container's height, you can set `position:relative` and set `position:absolute;` what you want div, will solve problem. Note: You should set `min-height`your absolute div for background color.

Comment: I want the height of the container to match the height of the longest child, in this case "p1", so I don't want to have it fixed

Comment: Hmm. Tried that, but not sure how to do it.

Comment: It still has the height in the parent, which I don't want. But thanks! :D

Answer (score 0):

First, you should set a `height` value for the  `container` div:

For instance:

```
#container {
    display: float;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height:50%;
    background-color: white; 
}
```

At present, your height for this div is the full height of the screen, hence the behaviour you are seeing.

Comment: I want the height of the container to match the height of the longest child, in this case "p1", so I don't want to have it fixed.

Comment: That gets asked a lot and there isn't a good solution for it.